# How to handle partial connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I try to create an reverse proxy that work bidirectional. its different from apache that stateless reverse proxy. its means, device can host webserver without public ip. so far i can reverse static content without any problem, css, javascript. but, something like media that return 206 code. it broken in middle. it stop reverse proxy, and try to keep run the server again and again. and i got the video load full. what the problem? i think, it okay already. cause, i jsut forward everything as binary. not specific coding.

reverse proxy port 80 forward to express server in port 8080

```
import net from 'net';

const server = new net.Server();

server.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('data', data => {
        const client = new net.Socket();
        client.connect({
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: 8080
        });

        client.write(data);

        client.on('data', data => {
            socket.write(data)
        })
    })
})

server.listen(80, () => {
    console.log('server is running')
});
```

Comment: You're making a new `client` socket every time your http client receives data. I think the issue is simply that you constantly create new connections.

Comment: @Evert if i as understand, A  (socket) is client send request to B, Reverse proxy, B (client) send request to real web server. if im not wrong, in `client.on` as long still there's buffer. it will keep do `socket.write` until no buffer

Comment: yes, but *every* time the `data` event triggers from `socket`, you make a new client currnently. You should make 1 client socket per 1 server socket

Comment: @Evert so i just need to give end connection each socket?

Comment: @Evert i just found out the solution. i read in net.server options. by default, net.server operate in stateless. it works one time only. by setting `allowHalfOpen` to true. server not close socket automatically after write operation.

Comment: @Evert my problem is now, how to detect and end socket. lets say, socket open from request to facebook. facebook html load many things, css, jss, video. how to know socket already load everything that html need? if i just open forever. each time user request to reverse proxy, previous socket still not close. and make server handle unuse socket.

Comment: You wait for the close event from both server and client, and if one closes you close the other one.